# ConditionalPanel with more than one condition are true

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am having a conditionalPanel problem when more than one option is valid.

A part of my code that the user makes two choices in sequence, so that filters are made in the database.

In the first choice, a State will be selected from a list of possibilities. It is important to know that the user can select more than one State.

In the second choice, the City will be selected from a list of possibilities. In this second choice, the user can also select more than one City.

As I said, important information is that the user can select more than one state, so from that multiple choice of states, it should be shown the cities of all selected states.

Everything works fine when the user selects only one state. The problem with my code starts when it selects more than one state, the ConditionalPanel simply disappears (nothing is shown, not even the first option that was already shown). It only appears again when the user removes the selections, keeping only one.

If anyone has a few minutes to help me to sort out this problem I'm facing, I'll be very grateful.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readr)

state_options <- c("1. Texas", "2. Massachusetts", "3. Colorado")
options_state_texas <- c("Alamo", "Alton", "Angus", "Atlanta", "Aurora", 
                         "Brownsboro", "Premont", "Princeton", "Red Oak",
                        "Staples", "Texas City")
options_state_massachusetts <- c("Boston", "Cambridge", "Chelsea", "Springfield")
options_state_colorado <- c("Aspen", "Aurora", "Avon", "Cortez", "Denver",
                            "Vail")


createMainPanel <- function(index_id) {
    mainPanel(
        width = 12,
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(
                strong("Split"),
                br(),
                box(
                    title = strong("State:"),
                    status = "primary",
                    width = 3,
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    checkboxGroupInput(
                        inputId = paste0(index_id, "_state"),
                        label = NULL,
                        choices = state_options
                    )
                ),
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.distribution_of_sales_sub_state == '1. Texas'",
                    box(
                        title = strong("Cities state 1:"),
                        status = "primary",
                        width = 3,
                        collapsible = TRUE,
                        checkboxGroupInput(
                            inputId = paste0(index_id, "_checkbox_city_1"),
                            label = NULL,
                            choices = options_state_texas
                        )
                    )
                ),
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.distribution_of_sales_sub_state == '2. Massachusetts'",
                    box(
                        title = strong("Cities state 2:"),
                        status = "primary",
                        width = 3,
                        collapsible = TRUE,
                        checkboxGroupInput(
                            inputId = paste0(index_id, "_checkbox_city_2"),
                            label = NULL,
                            choices = options_state_massachusetts
                        )
                    )
                ),
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.distribution_of_sales_sub_state == '3. Colorado'",
                    box(
                        title = strong("Cities state 3:"),
                        status = "primary",
                        width = 3,
                        collapsible = TRUE,
                        checkboxGroupInput(
                            inputId = paste0(index_id, "_checkbox_city_3"),
                            label = NULL,
                            choices = options_state_colorado
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
}

createTabItem <- function(title, index_id) {
    tabItem(
        tabName <- paste0(index_id, "_tab"),
        h2(title),
        createMainPanel(index_id))
}

createBox <- function(session, index_id, opcoes){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
        session,
        index_id,
        choices = c(opcoes))
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardSidebar(
        title = img(src='logo.png', height = 60, width = 180, style = "display: block; 
                    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"),
        HTML("<br><br>"),
        width = 230,
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem(strong("Sales"), tabName = "distribution_of_sales_sub_tab")
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            createTabItem(strong("Distribution of sales"),
                          "distribution_of_sales_sub")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) { 
    observe({
        createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_state", state_options)
        createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_checkbox_city_1", 
                  options_state_texas)
        createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_checkbox_city_2", 
                  options_state_massachusetts)
        createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_checkbox_city_3", 
                  options_state_colorado)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It might be easier to come up with a solution if you use the `selectInput` option rather than `checkbox` in which case you can achieve the functionality without using `conditionalPanel`

Comment: Thank's for your time, @krish
But if I use the selectInput, the user will not be able to select more than one state at a time, correct? And selecting more than one state is very frequent for analysis.

Comment: Both `selectInput` and `selectizeInput` have an argument called `multiple`. You can set this to `TRUE` which will allow multiple selections

Comment: Just in case you think using `selectizeInput` will be helpful, you can take a look at [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html)

Comment: Now that you have posted the entire code, how do you expect this to work when one selects more than one state? Should the cities be shown in one single menu for all the states or different menus one for each state?

Comment: Thank you, @krish.
I'm going to study about the selectizeInput. At least it may be a good feature for another problem that I need to solve. Thank you.
About your question, I was initially thinking of showing cities in different menus for each state, to facilitate user identification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your conditions to

```
condition = "input.distribution_of_sales_sub_state.includes('1. Texas')",

condition = "input.distribution_of_sales_sub_state.includes('2. Massachusetts')",

condition = "input.distribution_of_sales_sub_state.includes('3. Colorado')",
```

EDIT: SOLUTION FOR QUESTION IN COMMENTS

This definitely is not the best solution but this should give you what you want and a good start to make it better.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readr)

state_options <- c("1. Texas", "2. Massachusetts", "3. Colorado")
options_state_texas <- c("Alamo", "Alton", "Angus", "Atlanta", "Aurora", 
                         "Brownsboro", "Premont", "Princeton", "Red Oak",
                         "Staples", "Texas City")
options_state_massachusetts <- c("Boston", "Cambridge", "Chelsea", "Springfield")
options_state_colorado <- c("Aspen", "Aurora", "Avon", "Cortez", "Denver",
                            "Vail")

city_options <- c()

createMainPanel <- function(index_id) {
  mainPanel(
    width = 12,
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        strong("Split"),
        br(),
        box(
          title = strong("State:"),
          status = "primary",
          width = 3,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          checkboxGroupInput(
            inputId = paste0(index_id, "_state"),
            label = NULL,
            choices = state_options
          )
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.distribution_of_sales_sub_state != ''",
          uiOutput("city")
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

createTabItem <- function(title, index_id) {
  tabItem(
    tabName <- paste0(index_id, "_tab"),
    h2(title),
    createMainPanel(index_id))
}

createBox <- function(session, index_id, opcoes){
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(
    session,
    index_id,
    choices = c(opcoes))
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(
    title = img(src='logo.png', height = 60, width = 180, style = "display: block; 
                    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"),
    HTML("<br><br>"),
    width = 230,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(strong("Sales"), tabName = "distribution_of_sales_sub_tab")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      createTabItem(strong("Distribution of sales"),
                    "distribution_of_sales_sub")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  output$city <- renderUI({
    box(
      title = strong("Cities state:"),
      status = "primary",
      width = 3,
      collapsible = TRUE,
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = paste0("distribution_of_sales_sub", "_checkbox_city_1"),
        label = NULL,
        choices = cities()
      )
    )
  })
  city_options1 <- c()
  city_options2 <- c()
  city_options3 <- c()
  cities <- reactive({
    if(c("1. Texas") %in% input$distribution_of_sales_sub_state ){
      city_options1<- c(options_state_texas)
    }
    if (c("2. Massachusetts") %in% input$distribution_of_sales_sub_state) {
      city_options2 <- c(options_state_massachusetts)
    }
    if (c("3. Colorado") %in% input$distribution_of_sales_sub_state ) {
      city_options3 <- c(options_state_colorado)
    }
    city_options <- c(city_options1,city_options2, city_options3)
    city_options <- sort(city_options)
  })


  observe({
    createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_state", state_options)
    createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_checkbox_city_1", 
              options_state_texas)
    createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_checkbox_city_2", 
              options_state_massachusetts)
    createBox(session,"distribution_of_sales_sub_checkbox_city_3", 
              options_state_colorado)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Awesome, @krish! Thanks a lot for your help.
As you are helping me a lot, could you tell me what adaptation I should make if I need to put all the city options (from the chosen states) in a single menu in alphabetical order, please?

Comment: @PedroCortez, If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows. Meanwhile, I will look into getting the city options in a single menu. Thank you!

Comment: For sure, @krish! I was already going to make an accepted answer, I just had not done it because I believed that by checking that way, I would close the post. And I would still like to get that doubt out before closing.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @PedroCortez, I hope the edit with the other solution helps in what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not reproducible at all, You should take care of that before posting the question.

Well my guess without proper code and data would be to move all your conditions to `server.R`. So in `ui.R` you should create for each state: `uiOutput("state1")` (its for the first conditional state: Texas), then in `server.R`:

```
output$state1 <- renderUI({
 if(any(input$state == '1. Texas')){
box(
                            title = strong("Cities state 1:"),
                            status = "primary",
                            width = 3,
                            collapsible = TRUE,
                            checkboxGroupInput(
                                inputId = "checkbox_city_1"),
                                label = NULL,
                                choices = options_state_texas
                            )}
else{NULL})
```

Comment: Sorry for what happened, @Malvina_a. 
It was my first post here and I thought it was enough to show my problem.
I have already edited my post and put the whole code.
I hope now it is easier to understand and maybe find a solution to my problem.
In time, I tried to use your solution but I could not solve the problem. I do not know if I did anything else wrong = /